# LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001)

Tags: .net, visual-c++, linker, c++-cli, linker-errors

There are two existing A.vcxproj  and M.vcxproj .
A.vcxproj  output is (A.lib) & M.vcxproj  output type is (M.exe) .
In the M.vcproj project settings Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies A.Lib is given as input. Both the projects support Common Language Run Time Support(/clr). These two projects are succesfuly able to get build and M.exe is working fine.

Now to A.vcxproj , I have added two files EDBGW.h and EDBGW.cpp , where 
EDBGW.h file has :

```
public ref class EDBGW{
  public :
   EDBGW();
}
```

EDBGW.cpp has implementation of the constructor:

```
EDBGW::EDBGW(){

}
```

There is one more file R.h which includes EDBGW.h i.e.
in R.h

```
  #include "EDBGW.h"
```

Now When I build A.vcxproj , there are no build errors
But if I build M.vcxproj , there is a linker error

```
2>A.lib(R.obj) : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) EDBGW::.ctor
```

Note: I donot use EDBGW in M.vcproj at all.
But still I have this linker error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course you get that linker error.  The constructor lives in an entirely different executable file.

You have to de-tune the traditional C++ header-think a bit when you work with managed code.  It has very strong support for modules.  Assemblies in .NET speak.  They don't just store code, they also have metadata that describe the types in the assembly.  The equivalent of a .h file.

So you don't have to explicit export code anymore, you just declare the class *public*.  You already found that.  But then instead of #including a .h file, you add a reference to the assembly.  Right-click your M project, Properties, Common Properties, References.  Click the Add New Reference button.  Select your A project.

The compiler will now automatically know about your EDBGW class, it reads its declaration from the metadata in A.dll.  And it knows that it has to build A before M.  Binding to the constructor happens at runtime instead of build-time, performed by the just-in-time compiler.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that option, it did not worked. Note: I am not at all #including EDBGW.h directly in M.vcxproj . In A.vcxproj , I am #including EDBGW.h in R.h . This R.h has C++ class. Note it is not a ref class but has reference to EDBGW  as gcroot  . Should I not include EDBGW.h in R.h file also? If I remove then I get 24>R.h(95): error C2065: 'EDBGW' : undeclared identifier . Both the classes are in the same library i.e. A.lib

Comment: You cannot store managed code in a .lib file.  Static libraries were considered unnecessary since binding of managed code happens at runtime.  The linker doesn't support them.  It is very, very important to avoid having a managed class declared in more than one module, the CLR does not consider them identical.  You really have to get Add New Reference working.  No idea why the compiler is having a problem recognizing the class, maybe you forgot the namespace.

Comment: Now I have some options in my mind. 1. Making A.lib as A.dll and trying 2. What happens if I combine EDBGW.h and EDBGW.cpp into one file i.e EDBGW.h which also has the implementation  3. Rewriting EDBGW class as c++ class .

Comment: While it is true that you don't consume a C++/CLI assembly by including its public headers and lining with an import library, like you would for native DLLs, it isn't true that static libraries don't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a static library project, native or managed, it is best not to consume its .lib file via Additional Dependencies. Instead use a project reference as Hans detailed. You will also include the header files, contrary to Hans' s answer.

When you use a project reference, Visual Studio takes care of linking with the output of the other project, automatically causes the other project to be built first, and uses the matching build configuration (release vs debug, 32bit vs 64bit, etc.)

Another option you have when using project references to a static library project is to select the option "use library sources" or something like that, which causes all the object files from the library project to get linked in, without the usual pruning of objects that aren't used. Most likely you won't need this option though; I suspect your problems are caused by linking with an old copy of the .lib, a problem you won't have when using a project reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same linker error and wound up here but the cause turned out to be simple: `.ctor` means constructor. Make sure you remembered to implement your constructor. (Yes I'm a dill.)